# Odata Query with DataServiceContext and get result as json

Tags: wcf, odata, wcf-data-services

I have a DataServiceContext querying my WCF Data Service:

```
service = new DataServiceContext(new Uri(SvcUrl));
service.SendingRequest += new EventHandler<SendingRequestEventArgs>
(OnSendingRequest);
```

I want to set the Accept header so that I get the result as json:

```
    static void OnSendingRequest(object sender, SendingRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        e.RequestHeaders.Set("Accept", "json/text");
    }
```

But I get an exception:

> "This header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
>   Parameter name: name"

I cannot seem to figure out how else to set the Accept header.

Comment: Why would you want to specify the format, if you have the DataServiceContext process it for you? Would you ever see it? Still, the exception could have been more specific...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boooo hoo... just found this [msdn thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/cf849553-c4e4-4f3c-882b-216d7588108f).

The answer there says :

*"Since the client code is not written to handle json response, we don't allow Accept headers to be over-ridden. Your best bet would be to use HttpWebRequest directly and then handle the json response yourself."*